# jQuery if radio button is selected then proceed to next element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very new to JavaScript and jQuery. I know my code is not the prettiest, but I'm trying to start somewhere.

I have a series of questions that are shown one at a time, and want to create some sort of validation to prevent the user from going to the next question if a radio button on the first button hasn't been selected.

**HTML** (I have four of these `.questionContainers`

```
<div class="questionContainer">

<div class="question">
     How much storage do you need?
</div>

 <div class="answers">
     <ul>
         <li>
             <label>
                 <input type="radio" id="storage">1GB or less
             </label>
         </li>

         <li>
             <label>
                 <input type="radio" id="storage">More than 1GB
             </label>
         </li>  
     </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="btnContainer">
     <div class="next">
         <a class="btnNext">Next</a>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function(){

    var Questions = {

        container : $('.questionContainer'),

        init : function() {

            this.start();

            if($('input[type=radio]:checked').length > 0){
                this.container.find('a.btnNext').on('click', this.next);
            }

        },

        start : function() {

            this.container.not(':first').addClass('hide');
        },

        next : function() {

            var container = $('.questionContainer');

            $(this).closest(container).hide(function(){
                $(this).closest(container).next().show();       
            });
        }
    };
    Questions.init();
})();
```

The specific line that isn't working:

```
if($('input[type=radio]:checked').length > 0) {

   this.container.find('a.btnNext').on('click', this.next);
}
```

The Problem

When I add the if statement and click a radio button followed by next, it does not go to the next question. I am not receiving any errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *binds* to the click event only if something is checked at the time that the start function is called (not what you want - it will never be true unless you pre-select a radio button for the user without their action):

```
        if($('input[type=radio]:checked').length > 0){
            this.container.find('a.btnNext').on('click', this.next);
        }
```

Try replacing it with this instead:

```
this.container.find('a.btnNext').on('click', function () {
        if($('input[type=radio]:checked').length > 0){
            this.next();
        }
});
```

This way you always bind to the click event, but the function that is bound only allows `next` to be called if something is checked at the time that the function is called (i.e. when the next button is clicked).

Comment: Your solution completely clears up the problem for me, but for some reason the `next();` function isn't being called. I know that the if statement is working because to test, I alerted a message. I tried changing `this.next()` to `Questions.next()`, but it still isn't working

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint inside the `next` function? Maybe the function is being called but is not doing what you expect?

Comment: Ah, I just realized why the next function doesn't seem to be working. I had written it to be dependent on the click event, now `this` seems to reference the entire `Questions` object instead of the anchor tag. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Oh, you can just use `$(this).next();` - that should call `next` on the object that was clicked. Otherwise if it doesn't work (if it expects the Questions namespace), you can change the function to take in the clicked object as a parameter and call it like this: `Questions.next($(this));`

Comment: Hmm neither worked, though I definitely expected the `Questions.next($(this));` to fix it. I will accept your answer as it did answer my initial question and problem. I think I'm going to have to use the `call` method to pass `this` though to `next()` Thanks for your help

Comment: If you use `Questions.next($(this))`, you'd have to modify the `next` function to take in a parameter, and to use that parameter within the `next` function instead of `$(this)`: `next: function(param) {
            var container = $('.questionContainer');
            param.closest(container).hide(function(){
                param.closest(container).next().show();       
            });
        }`